# dhtmlmodal window height width issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jqmodal

I am using the dhtmlmodal window of dynamic drive
[(http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex8/dhtmlwindow/)](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex8/dhtmlwindow/)

please help me out.. i spent around three days in a row just to get this done. I even tried colorbox plugin and it also kept messing up. 
thanks in advance

i am trying to load my form into it which have a specified set of styling.
actually when i load it using "iframe" or "ajax" the form loads into modal but it is not as per the desired width and height. and even the form content looks messy.

here is the html for form

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html lang="en" class="no-js ie6 lt8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie7 lt8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie8 lt8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<title>Login and Registration Form with HTML5 and CSS3</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
</head>
<body bgcolor="red">
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="login">
<table>
<tr>
 <td>
  <form action="mysuperscript.php" autocomplete="on">
   <h1>Log in</h1>
   <p>
    <label>Username</label>
    <br>
    <input id="username" name="username" required="required" type="text" Username"
    />
   </p>
   <p>
    <label>Your password</label>
    <br>
    <input id="password" name="password" required="required" type="password"
    />
   </p>
   <p class="signin button">
    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
   </p>
   <p class="change_link">
    Not a member yet?   <a href="">Join us</a>
   </p>
  </form>
  </td>
  <td>
  <section class="logformside-container">
   <h1>Log in with</h1>
   <div>
    <span class="button">
     <a href="#">
      <img src="images/facebook.png" alt="">Login with facebook</a>
    </span>
    <br>
    <span class="button">
     <a href="#">
      <img src="images/twitter_standing.png" alt="">Login with twitter</a>
    </span>
    <br>
    <span class="button">
     <a href="#">
      <img src="images/mail.png" alt="">Login with gmail</a>
    </span>
   </div>
  </section>
 </td>
 </tr></table>
 </div></div></body></html>
```

here is its styling...

```
.wrapper {
width:680px;
}
/**** Styling the form elements **/
/**** general text styling ****/
.wrapper a {
color: rgb(95, 155, 198);
text-decoration: none;}
.wrapper h1 {
font-size: 24px;
color: rgb(6, 106, 117);
padding: 2px 0 10px 0;
font-family: 'FranchiseRegular','Arial Narrow',Arial,sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: center;
}
.wrapper h4 {
font-size: 20px;
color: rgb(6, 106, 117);
padding: 2px 0 10px 0;
font-family: 'FranchiseRegular','Arial Narrow',Arial,sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: center;}
/** For the moment only webkit supports the background-clip:text; */
.wrapper h1,
.wrapper h4 {
background: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, 
rgb(18, 83, 93) , 
rgb(18, 83, 93) 20px, 
rgb(64, 111, 118) 20px, 
rgb(64, 111, 118) 40px, 
rgb(18, 83, 93) 40px);
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
-webkit-background-clip: text;
}
/**** advanced input styling ****/
/* placeholder */
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
color: rgb(190, 188, 188);
font-style: italic;
}
input:-moz-placeholder,
textarea:-moz-placeholder {
color: rgb(190, 188, 188);
font-style: italic;
}
input {
outline: focus;
}
/* all the input except submit and checkbox */
.wrapper input:not([type="checkbox"]) {
width: 80%;
margin-top: 4px;
padding: 10px 5px 10px;
border: 1px solid #c7d0d2;
border-radius: 2px;
font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
outline: none;
box-shadow: inset 0 1.5px 3px rgba(190, 190, 190, .4), 0 0 0 5px #f5f7f8;
-webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
-moz-transition: all .4s ease;
transition: all .4s ease;
}
.wrapper input:not([type="checkbox"]):active,
.wrapper input:not([type="checkbox"]):focus {
border: 1px solid #a8c9e4;
box-shadow: inset 0 1.5px 3px rgba(190, 190, 190, .4), 0 0 0 5px #e6f2f9;
} 
/*styling both submit buttons */
.wrapper p.button input {
width: 80px;
cursor: pointer;
padding: 8px 5px;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: bold;
color: #fff;
background-color: #acd6ef;
margin-left: 45px;
}
.wrapper p.button input:hover
.wrapper p.button input:active,
.wrapper p.button input:focus {
 position: relative;
 top: 1px;
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top left 90deg, #6ec2e8 0%, #b6e2ff 100%);
 background-image: linear-gradient(top left 90deg, #6ec2e8 0%, #b6e2ff 100%);
 }
p.signin.button {
text-align: right;
margin: 5px 0;
}
.login p.change_link a {
display: inline-block;
font-weight: bold;
background: rgb(247, 248, 241);
 padding: 2px 6px;
 color: rgb(29, 162, 193);
 margin-left: 10px;
 text-decoration: none;
 -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
 border-radius: 4px;
 border: 1px solid rgb(203, 213, 214);
 -webkit-transition: all 0.4s linear;
 -moz-transition: all 0.4s  linear;
 -o-transition: all 0.4s linear;
 -ms-transition: all 0.4s  linear;
transition: all 0.4s  linear;
 } 
.login p.change_link a:hover {
 color: rgb(57, 191, 215);
 background: rgb(247, 247, 247);
border: 1px solid rgb(74, 179, 198);
 }
.login p.change_link a:active {
 position: relative;
 }
/** Styling both forms **/
.login {
position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 padding: 0 10px 60px 10px;
 background: rgb(247, 247, 247);
 border: 1px solid rgba(147, 184, 189,0.8);
 -webkit-box-shadow: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 border-radius: 5px;
}
.login table,.register table {
 width: 100%;
 }

 .login td,.register td {
 width: 50%;
 }
section.logformside-container {
margin-left: 20px;
 margin-top: 27px;
 border-left: 2px solid rgb(219, 229, 232);
 height: 280px;
}
section.logformside-container div {
 margin-left:50px;
}
section.regformside-container {
 margin-top: -106px;
 border-left: 2px solid rgb(219, 229, 232);
 height: 560px;
}
section.regformside-container div {
 margin-left: 80px;
}
.reg-benefits {
 margin-top: 100px;
}
.button a {
 font-family: arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 13px;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 white;
 background: #ffffff;
 -moz-border-radius: 3px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
 padding: 6px 12px;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #333333;
 }
.button a:hover {
 background: #ffffff;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
 }
.button a:active {
background: #dfdfdf;}
.button a > img {
 padding-right: 8px;
 position: relative;
}
```

this is the js for modal window i downloaded,

```
var dhtmlmodal={
veilstack: 0,
open:function(t, contenttype, contentsource, title, attr, recalonload){
var d=dhtmlwindow //reference dhtmlwindow object
 this.interVeil=document.getElementById("interVeil") //Reference "veil" div
 this.veilstack++ //var to keep track of how many modal windows are open right now
  this.loadveil()
if (recalonload=="recal" && d.scroll_top==0)
     d.addEvent(window, function(){dhtmlmodal.adjustveil()}, "load")
 var t=d.open(t, contenttype, contentsource, title, attr, recalonload)
t.controls.firstChild.style.display="none" //Disable "minimize" button
 t.controls.onclick=function(){dhtmlmodal.close(this._parent, true)}
 t.show=function(){dhtmlmodal.show(this)}
t.hide=function(){dhtmlmodal.close(this)}
 return t
 },


loadveil:function(){
 var d=dhtmlwindow
d.getviewpoint()
 this.docheightcomplete= 

(d.standardbody.offsetHeight>d.standardbody.scrollHeight)?   
 d.standardbody.offsetHeight : d.standardbody.scrollHeight
this.interVeil.style.width=d.docwidth+"px" //set up veil over page
 this.interVeil.style.height=this.docheightcomplete+"px" //set up veil over page
 this.interVeil.style.left=0 //Position veil over page
 this.interVeil.style.top=0 //Position veil over page
this.interVeil.style.visibility="visible" //Show veil over page
this.interVeil.style.display="block" //Show veil over page
},

adjustveil:function(){ //function to adjust veil when window is resized
 if (this.interVeil && this.interVeil.style.display=="block")
    this.loadveil() //readjust veil},

closeveil:function(){ 
 this.veilstack--
 if (this.veilstack==0) 
    this.interVeil.style.display="none"
 },


close:function(t, forceclose){ //DHTML modal close function
t.contentDoc=
 (t.contentarea.datatype=="iframe")?   window.frames["_iframe-"+t.id].document: 

 t.contentarea
 if (typeof forceclose!="undefined")
     t.onclose=function(){return true}
 if (dhtmlwindow.close(t)) //if close() returns true
     this.closeveil()
 },


show:function(t){
 dhtmlmodal.veilstack++
 dhtmlmodal.loadveil()
dhtmlwindow.show(t)
 }
} //END object declaration
document.write('<div id="interVeil"></div>')
dhtmlwindow.addEvent(window, function(){if (typeof dhtmlmodal!="undefined") 
dhtmlmodal.adjustveil()}, "resize")
```

and here is its styling

```
.drag-handle{ /*Overwrite default drag handle bar background color with below*/
background-color: #03277C;
}

#interVeil{ /*CSS for veil that covers entire page while modal window is visible*/
position: absolute;
background: black url(blackdot.gif);
width: 10px;
left: 0;
top: 0;
z-index: 5;
visibility: hidden;
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.alpha(opacity=80);
opacity: 0.8;
}
```

the main page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="windowfiles/dhtmlwindow.css" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="windowfiles/dhtmlwindow.js">


</script>

<body>



 <!-- 3) DHTML Window Example 3: -->

<p>Play around with Window 3 (Ajax content)</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
function openmypage(){
ajaxwin=dhtmlwindow.open("ajaxbox", "ajax", "a.html","TITLE", 

"width=680px,height=380px,center=1,left=300px,top=100px,resize=1,scrolling=0")
ajaxwin.onclose=function(){return window.confirm("Close window 3?")}
}
</script>
<ul>
<li><b><a href="#" onClick="openmypage(); return false">Create/ Open Window</a>
</b>     </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Wow. dynamicdrive.com still exists? Good old friend.

Comment: @BatuZet can ya help??

Comment: I can only say, try to use jquery ui modal instead o.o sorry

Comment: @BatuZet can ya please provide me the proper downloading link